# How to install oracle10g?

Tags: 11.10, server, oracle

I want to install oracle10g on my ubuntu 11.10 server but it has
this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-xe
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what commands you issued to try and install oracle10g?  Also, did yuo add the Oracle repo for the program?

Comment: It's telling you what's wrong right there *requested operation requires superuser privilege*.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**

Add the following lines to the /etc/apt/sources.list

Oracle Repository

```
deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free
```

**Step 2:**

import the key

```
wget http://oss.oracle.com/el4/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Step 3:**

Update the package repository database by using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Step 4:**

Install the Oracle Express packages:

```
sudo aptitude install oracle-xe oracle-xe-client
```

**Step 5:**

Configure the oracle as per ur need

```
sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
```

**Step 6:**

Access the nice Oracle web interface by:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex
```

Comment: What about a 64 bit System?

Answer (score 0):

You should be following the process found at the link below. If not, please follow it and post additional details as to what step in your process you are encountering the error.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle