# How to Install Oracle 10g on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, installation, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install oracle10g?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94687/how-to-install-oracle10g)

Is it possible to install oracle 10g on Ubuntu 11.10?

During installation process I got errors like:

```
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
```